# Not able to use Service method from Kendo Grid Component

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

i have a component in angular which is using directive kendoGridSelectBy and calling a funtion test , i want to call a service method 'check' in test but its not getting Called, whereas other funtions in this component can use this service method.

HTML Code

```
<kendo-grid
[kendoGridSelectBy]="test"
>
```

TS Code

```
 test(context: RowArgs): number {
    this.testService.check();
 }
```

It says testService is undefined however i have imported the same in TS file.